# slick column not defined

Tags: scala, slick

I am new in scala slick  .
why can not found column and O in slick v3.1.1
please view this example code :

```
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver
import slick.lifted.Tag
import slick.model.Table ;

case class Person(id:Int,name:String)

class Persons(tag: Tag) extends Table[Person](tag , "PERSONS") {
    def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def name = column[String]("name", O.NotNull)
}
```

**Update :**
I use this document :   http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/gettingstarted.html#schema

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply change your import to:

```
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._
```

Looking at your code - this should be the only import that you should need (at least at this stage).

Comment: ohh , yes thank you , I must replace that with import slick.model.Table ;

Answer (score 0):

For the latest versions of slick you can use:

```
import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._
```

So you don't see the **deprecated** message